# SQL Scripting Creating a view instead of derived table

Tags: sql-server

So This is a school question similar to another I was given a code:

```
USE AP

SELECT VendorName, FirstInvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices JOIN
  (SELECT VendorID, MIN(InvoiceDate) AS FirstInvoiceDate
   FROM Invoices
   GROUP BY VendorID) AS FirstInvoice
  ON (Invoices.VendorID = FirstInvoice.VendorID AND
      Invoices.InvoiceDate = FirstInvoice.FirstInvoiceDate)
JOIN Vendors
  ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
ORDER BY VendorName, FirstInvoiceDate
```

I need to change this to create a view instead of a derived table I was thinking something more like

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views
        Where name = ‘EarliestInvoiceandTotalVEW’)


CREATE View AS
Select VendorName, FirstInvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal
From Invoices JOIN
    (Create VIEW FirstInvoice AS
    SELECT VendorID, MIN(InvoiceDate) AS FirstInvoiceDate
    From Invoices
    Group By VendorID) As FirstInvoice
    ON (Invoices.VendorID = FirstInvoice.VendorID AND
      Invoices.InvoiceDate = FirstInvoice.FirstInvoiceDate)
JOIN Vendors
  ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
ORDER BY VendorName, FirstInvoiceDate
```

This would make a view to do the same thing and check if it exists so it is not recreated/defined each time.

Thanks for any input on this!

I apologize about the format I took it directly out of SQL Server and it normally is formatted well...

This is what I got to work:

```
 USE AP
 Declare @Create1 varchar(8000)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views Where sys.views.name = 'EarliestInvoiceandTotalVIEW')
    drop view EarliestInvoiceandTotalVIEW;

SET @CREATE1 = 'CREATE View EarliestInvoiceTotalVIEW AS 
Select VendorName, FirstInvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal
From Invoices JOIN
  (SELECT VendorID, MIN(InvoiceDate) AS FirstInvoiceDate
   FROM Invoices
   GROUP BY VendorID) AS FirstInvoice
  ON (Invoices.VendorID = FirstInvoice.VendorID AND
      Invoices.InvoiceDate = FirstInvoice.FirstInvoiceDate)
JOIN Vendors
  ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID'

Exec (@CREATE1)
```

I had to set the where to sys.views.name =... as well as set an exec command so that the create view is running 'first'.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The second part comes up with errors for me:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '‘'.
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Create'.
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Though I have been working on this so long I could be doing something wrong. Is this correct or where am I messing up?

Comment: You did not specified view name in `create`, it should be `create view [EarliestInvoiceandTotalVEW] as --etc.`

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment, be sure to surround your view definition with `GO` statements:

```
if exists (select * from sys.views where name = 'ThreeDigitsOfPi')
    drop view dbo.ThreeDigitsOfPi
GO
create view dbo.ThreeDigitsOfPi 
as
select  3.14 as PI
GO
```

Some other points:

- You should use single quotes `'` instead of `‘` style quotes
- Your view has to have a name (`create view NameOfView as ...`)
- An `view` definition cannot follow an `if` statement, unless the view is created in dynamic SQL.  For example: `if not exists (...) exec('create view ...')`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to check if a view exists.  However, often the approach is to delete a view if it exists and then recreate it:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views Where name = ‘EarliestInvoiceandTotalVEW’)
    drop view EarliestInvoiceandTotalVEW;
```

Then, your `create view` statement has two flaws.  First it is lacking a name.  Second it has an embedded `create view` in it.  You have to decide which one you want to create -- a view for the subquery or a view for the entire statement (it is not clear to me from the question which is the right approach).

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction. Ultimately this is what I got to work (didn't get the order by to work (yet?))
I will edit my post with what I got to work.

Comment: @DanielErb . . . `order by`s in views are not guaranteed to have any effect unless you are using `top` in the view itself.